# Generate an frequency response from impulse response matlab

Tags: matlab

I used the code, that given below, to generate impulse response of sound that, how can i generate frequency response from impulse response?

```
clc;clear;close all;   
u = audiorecorder;

disp('Start speaking.') 
recordblocking(u, 25);  
disp('end recording.');    
play(u)  
x=getaudiodata(u);  
plot(x)
```

Comment: Do you know of `fft`?